# ffplay cannot play aac and mp4a (which is aac audio in an mp4 file) and ffprobe segfaults when given a file with aac audio

Tags: linux, audio, ffmpeg, gentoo, ffprobe

When I try to play a file with aac audio in ffplay, I get the following error: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1M1oCITTuaLMsLo0bs6lGbw9mZTzdwwBB/view?usp=sharing

Also, when I do `ffprobe sample-1.aac`, the program segfaults for some reason. Same things happen with ffplay and ffprobe when I give it a video file with aac audio:

ffplay: https://drive.google.com/file/d/14hoBFtdUCIdN58xBmwRCHWiEKqjO5CSE/view?usp=sharing

ffprobe: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CBJda1n7gzPzxWnaIA5vYiCS8cMmywaY/view?usp=sharing

Media info for `sample-1.aac`: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1koYkYjEgfofRxacRFQnXCk_wcSzEHs-M/view?usp=sharing

Media info for `Sample Video - 720p.mp4`: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ffvMbgALFqu1JT74Tn6U4Ddo7D9BjSih/view?usp=sharing

I have no idea why this is happening, but I'm guessing that for some reason, ffprobe crashes and therefore causes ffplay to crash.

I am running Gentoo Linux on a MacBook pro late 2013 (15"). My cpu is an `i7-4750HQ` and I believe it has Iris Pro Graphics 5200 (which is an Intel Gen7 integrated GPU). It has no dedicated GPU.

My use flags for ffmpeg are: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pqax4W9DgAe4ISEu2qD9YDZWdcZaqyUr/view?usp=sharing

Also, my COMMON_FLAGS is set to `-O2 -pipe -march=native -mtune=native`, my MAKEOPTS is set to `-j3`, and VIDEO_CARDS is set to `intel fbdev`.

Could anybody tell me why is this happening and how do I fix this?

**EDIT:**

I disabled the vaapi USE flag for ffmpeg, but it didn't fix anything.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Try disabling `vaapi` use flag?

Comment: @binki, I've disabled the vaapi USE flag, but that didn't change anything.

Comment: Can you please upload any screenshots using our image host? I am not interested in clicking links to a random and untrusted Google drive share.